# C++ error: 'variable' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I have this simple C++ program and when I try to compile it I get two errors:
`'klasa' was not declared in this scope`
`'oznaka' was not declared in this scope`

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Note: I am still beginner in C++. :]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    if(T>=73){
        string klasa = "A";
        string oznaka = "XL";
    }
    else if(63<=T && T<73){
        string klasa = "A";
        string oznaka = "L";
    }
    else if(53<=T && T<63){
        string klasa = "A";
        string oznaka = "M";
    }
    else if(43<=T && T<53){
        string klasa = "A";
        string oznaka = "S";
    }
    else if(T<43){
        string klasa = "B";
        string oznaka = "XS";
    }

    cout << klasa << " " << oznaka;
}
```

Comment: The lifetime of each `klasa` is restricted to the *scope* (i.e. the surrounding curly braces) in which it is declared. One solution is to declare a single `klasa` where you declare `T`. Ditto `oznaka`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you're declaring each of `klasa` and `oznaka` inside the "if statement", as such you can only reach these variables within their scope (i.e inside each of their respective "if statements")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    string klasa = "";
    string oznaka = "";

    if(T>=73){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "XL";
    }
    else if(63<=T && T<73){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "L";
    }
    else if(53<=T && T<63){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "M";
    }
    else if(43<=T && T<53){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "S";
    }
    else if(T<43){
        klasa = "B";
        oznaka = "XS";
    }

    cout << klasa << " " << oznaka;
}
```

The code above places the declaration of the variables in a more global scope, so you can access them inside the "if statements" and outside of them too.

Answer (score 1):

Along with declaring the variables outside of the scope of the conditionals, I'd also reverse your order of the comparisons to make it read better and less chance of making a mistake:

```
string klasa, oznaka;

if (T < 43) {
    klasa = "B";
    oznaka = "XS";
}
else if (T < 53) {
    klasa = "A";
    oznaka = "S";
}
else if (T < 63) {
    klasa = "A";
    oznaka = "M";
}
else if (T < 73) {
    klasa = "A";
    oznaka = "L";
}
else {
    klasa = "A";
    oznaka = "XL";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are declared in a scope. `{` opens a scope and `}` closes a scope. Within a scope you can access variables from outside scopes but not from inside scopes.

You can think of it like storeys of a building. On each floor, you can only look down, not up.

```
int main() { // "ground-level"
    int x = 0;

    { // "1st floor"
        x = 1;     // we can "look down" 

        { // "2nd floor" 
            int y = 0;
            x = 2;
        }
     
        y = 1;     // error ! we cannot "look up"

        { // another "2nd floor", but not connected to above
             x = 3;
             y = 2; // error ! (there are no "windows to look horizontally")
        }
    }

}
```

For your case, that means you need to declare the variables outside of the `if` if you want to access them outside of the `if`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    std::string klasa;
    std::string oznaka;
    if(...){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "XL";
    }
    std::cout << klasa << " " << oznaka;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Read the code to get the explanation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int T;      // T is defined here and exists until the closing bracket
    cin >> T;

    if(T>=73){
        string klasa = "A"; // klasa is defined here
        string oznaka = "XL"; // oznaka is defined from here on.
    } // here klasa, and oznaka don't exist anymore.
    else if(63<=T && T<73){
        string klasa = "A"; // a different klasa is defined here
        string oznaka = "L"; // a different oznaka is defined here.
        // the second set of klasa & oznaka cease to exist after this point.
    } // here klasa, and oznaka don't exist anymore.
    else if(53<=T && T<63){
        string klasa = "A"; // a third klasa is defined here.
        string oznaka = "M"; // a third oznaka is defined here.
        // the third group cease to exist after this point.
    } // here klasa, and oznaka don't exist anymore.
    else if(43<=T && T<53){
        string klasa = "A"; // Idem....
        string oznaka = "S";
    } // here klasa, and oznaka don't exist anymore.
    else if(T<43){
        string klasa = "B";
        string oznaka = "XS";
    } // here klasa, and oznaka don't exist anymore.

    // neither klasa nor oznaka are defined at this point, only T
    // (and cin with is defined in the global scope, outside of main())

    cout << klasa << " " << oznaka; // error.
} // here, T doesn't exist anymore.
```

this code will do the work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    string klasa = "?";  // put some initializer here.
    string oznaka = "?"; // and here.

    if(T>=73){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "XL";
    }
    else if(63<=T && T<73){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "L";
    }
    else if(53<=T && T<63){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "M";
    }
    else if(43<=T && T<53){
        klasa = "A";
        oznaka = "S";
    }
    else if(T<43){
        klasa = "B";
        oznaka = "XS";
    }

    // so if you get here with klasa or oznaka having "?" you can test
    // that you have not covered all the possible values in the tests
    // above.

    cout << klasa << " " << oznaka;
}
```